# exclude a category from woocommerce discount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, discount

The following working code is a discount for cart with minimum 3 items not including 'sale' products Now I need to ignore categoty 'gift' (if it is in the cart) from this discount:

```
//10% discount at minimum 3 items in cart not for sale items
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'custom_cart_discount', 20, 1);
function custom_cart_discount( $cart ){
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
return;
// Limitations: Only when there is 5 or more non on sale items in cart
$starting_limit = 3;
// Initialising variables
$not_on_sale_subtotal = $discount = $items_count = 0;
// Iterating through each item in cart
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
// For cart items is not on sale
if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ){
    $not_on_sale_subtotal += (float) $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
    $items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
}
}
// Discount calculation
$discount = $not_on_sale_subtotal * 0.1;
// Applied discount only cart items that are not on sale
if( $discount && $items_count >= $starting_limit )
$cart->add_fee( 'הנחת כמות 10%', -$discount );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to work with a different approach. WooCommerce Coupons gives you a full control for what you want to achieve.

First, create a coupon in WC admin, with the 10% discount. Then, use the coupon settings to apply it on the cart or just on specific items/categories. You can see in the coupon limitations how exactly to limit the discount to specific categories (with include / exclude ), or to apply the discount only on items that are not on sale etc...

Finally, all you have to do, is just to ask or encourage the customer to apply the coupon, or automatically apply it yourself behind the scenes with:

```
WC()->cart->apply_coupon('YouCouponCodeGoesHere');
```

בהצלחה!